# FieldErrorでどこが引っかかっているのかわからない。

Tags: python3, django

[image]

[image]

publidhed_dateというスペルミスをpublished_dateに直したのですが、いまだにこのエラーが出てしまいます。

そして、これがどこのファイルでエラーになっているのかわかりません。templatesフォルダーの下にあるすべてのhtmlをctrl+fで検索をかけて探したのですが、みつかりません。

このエラーが出たときは、どこにそのエラーのあるファイルがあるかどうすれば発見できますか？

[image: tree]

ちなみにテンプレートでpublished_dateを使っているのは、post_detail.htmlのみです。

[image]

Answer (score 1):

過去のtypoを修正後も、期待通りに動作しないのであれば、

1. ファイルを保存していない
2. どこかにキャッシュファイルが残っていてそっちを見ている
3. サーバー上にデプロイされていない

今回は、修正後のhtmlファイルがデプロイされずに、ひとつ前のものが使われているのでは？
と思いますが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: いまローカルでランサーバーで走らせている状態です。かつ、保存は自動で行われるので、普段は、サーバー走らせながら編集してもダイレクトに変更が反映されるようになっています。なので、1,3は当てはまらなさそうです。キャッシュファイルに関してもうすこし調べてみます。